# False section of condition resolved even when condition is true

Tags: c#, reflection, dll

I lately have had to change a piece of code to allow compatibility with an older version DLL. The DLLs have the same name and are not signed. The difference also is in some additional methods added to the new DLL.

One way to go about this which doesn't seem right to me is to reference the new DLL in the project, build and run. If you want to use the other DLL, you just replace it in the bin folder. You can avoid errors by just checking the existence of a method in a constructor somewhere using Reflection, and set a flag so that later on you can avoid calling the new functions if you are using the older version.

The strange thing to me is that the following piece of code doesn't work when using the old version:

```
int[] someVariable = (DLLIsNewFormat) ? DLL.CallNewMethod() : new int[5];
```

Basically what is happening is that the DLLIsNewFormat is False but for some reason I get the error:

> Method not found: 'Int32[] [NameSpace].[Class].CallNewMethod()'.

I understand that the best way to go about this is to probably check if each function exists and then calling them using reflection. But I just don't know why the code is behaving this way. Is this just undefined behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening at the time that the method containing your snippet is JIT-compiled.  In order for JIT-compilation to happen, the method needs to be available at the time the method is invoked.  Since the method is not available, the JIT-compiler throws this exception when the method containing this code is called, before the method is even executed.

One way around this would be to define a new method:

```
int[] HideCall()
{
    return DLL.CallNewMethod();
}
```

Then call this method instead of `DLL.CallNewMethod()` directly.

A better solution would be to define an interface in an assembly that is referenced by both your "conditional DLL" and the assembly you are conditionally using this DLL from.  Have a default implementation of this interface available in the main assembly, and an alternate implementation in the conditionally-used DLL.

Then, at runtime, you can simply see if the DLL is available, use reflection to construct an instance of the class that implements this interface, and then substitute out a the reference to your default implementation with this one.

Example code:

```
// Interface, in an assembly visible to both of the other assemblies.
public interface IDLLInterface
{
    int[] CallNewMethod();
}

// Implementation in the main program.
class DefaultDLLImplementation : IDLLInterface
{
    public int[] CallNewMethod()
    {
        return new int[5];
    }
}

static class DLLImplementation
{
    public readonly IDLLInterface Instance;

    static DLLImplementation()
    {
        // Pseudo-code
        if (DllIsAvailable) {
            Instance = ConstructInstanceFromDllUsingReflection();
        } else {
            Instance = new DefaultDLLImplementation();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `DLLImplementation.Instance.CallNewMethod()` instead, and the right method will be called automatically.

Of course, I would suggest naming your interface with a more descriptive name so that it's apparent what it means.

Comment: Oh yes I see why the method is being resolved now. Thank you for your answer cdhowie. The interface solution seems neat, I'll take note of that for later uses. Unfortunately as I can't change the previous compiled versions of the dll. I can't use this approach. Hiding the calls or going reflection all the way seem to be the only options. I don't really like hiding the method since I think it makes the code ugly as there are around 10 new methods and I have to have 10 dummy methods just to hide them. Reflection on the other hand could have performance implications but acceptable ones maybe.

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo As an alternative, you can implement the "external DLL" class inside of your main assembly and conditionally construct an instance of it, falling back on a default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to hide calls to non-existing methods from JIT.

To do so you need to make sure each of non-existent calls made in inside a function and *call* to such function is controlled by version condition:

```
private int[] WrappedNewMethod()
{
  return DLL.CallNewMethod();
}

...SomeOtherMethod()
{
   int[] someVariable = (DLLIsNewFormat) ? WrappedNewMethod(): new int[5];
}
```

Comment: Hmm....I see. Can you elaborate why JIT would try to resolve the call to that function? Is this some form of optimization? branch prediction? Because after all JIT is here to only compile parts of the code that are needed right?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo smallest unit JIT compiles separately is a method. As result all calls inside the method must be available to be potentially called (but these methods themselves don't need to be JIT-ed unless actually called).  cdhowie's answer have explanation too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alexei. I don't really have upvote privileges or I would have upvoted you ! :)